# Why is state not transitioning to "payment_pending" for orders cancelled at gateway?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am using Magento community ver1.6.1.0.
I found this state diagram on Magento wiki http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/order_management

[image]

My problem is the state switching as shown by bold red lines.
When a user goes away from my (merchant) site, the state is new (status=pending). But if the customer does not completes payment (at payment gateway), the status is still "pending", whereas it should be "pending_payment". In "pending_payment" state, staff will call the customer to ask for any trouble.

So my question is, why are state transitioning as per this diagram? Or am I missing something? How do I solve this? because it is hard to distinguish between COD "pending" and such "aborted" orders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a cron job to change state from "pending" to "pending payment". It does the job, and can be configured to take care that new orders are not transitioned. Also a simple mail function can be added to notify the staff, when this transition is made.

The complete answer (by me) is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11131787/558094