# How to change the order state programmatically inside a cron job?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I am using a cron job to change all "pending" net-banking orders to "payment-pending"
(this is to solve my problem : [Why is state not transitioning to "payment_pending" for orders cancelled at gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11078751/558094))

This is my code-
**[EDITED]**

```
const MINUTES_DELAY = 15; //Orders younger than this are not changed

public function run() {

  //      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
  $old_time = time() - (self::MINUTES_DELAY*60);
  $out = date('d.m.y h:i:s A', $old_time)."\n";
  $out .= date('d.m.y h:i:s A')."\n";
  file_put_contents('/home/vinayak/cron.txt', '1'.$out, FILE_APPEND); //Out1

  $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending')
    ->addFieldToFilter('cod_fee', array('null' => true))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ;
  foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if (strtotime($order->getCreatedAt()) < $old_time){
      $order->setState('pending_payment', true)->save();
      $out .= $order->getCustomerEmail()." @ ".$order->getCreatedAt()."\n";
    }
  }
  file_put_contents('/home/vinayak/cron.txt', '2'.$out, FILE_APPEND); //Out2

  return true;
}
```

I have checked that cron is working. But the state/status is not changing. I am **not** getting error now.

**[EDITED]** Problem Now - 
I am getting output marked as "out1" in the code, but not the "out2"

After varying the code, I have seen that, whenever `if` condition is true the problem (above) occurs. This points out the problem with the line `$order->setState('pending_payment', true)->save();` (I have commented out the other line in `if`, and the problem persists, but if I comment out this line out2 gets printed). It seems as if the execution gets stuck up at this line (infinite loop? or some internal problem?)

What's wrong with `$order->setState('pending_payment', true)->save();`? Any other way to accomplish the said thing?

<s>Can I also filter by order "creation time", so that I don't change the state for order, which was created seconds ago.</s>[SOLVED]

Thanks!

Comment: If you run the script without the cron does it changes status?  If not can you narrow down which line is causing the problem?  I'm thinking the issue might be either with the getModel or setState.

Comment: @Rachael: Edited the question. The problem is with `setState`.

Comment: Where do you add this code?

Comment: @LouisW: I created a module for Cron jobs. IIRC I added this code in /app/code/local/SOMENAME/Cron/Model/Observer.php. But I no longer work on this so I don't remember much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem. Now the job works exactly as intended!

This is the working program-

```
  const MINUTES_DELAY = 15; //Orders younger than this are not changed
  const OUT_FILE = '/home/vinayak/cron.txt';

  public function run() {
    $old_time = time() - (self::MINUTES_DELAY*60);

    $out = "-------------------------------------------\n";
    $out .= date('d.m.y h:i:s A')."\n";

    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending')
      ->addFieldToFilter('cod_fee', array('null' => true))
      ;

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
      if (strtotime($order->getCreatedAt()) < $old_time)  {
        try{
          $id = $order->getIncrementId();

          Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->loadByIncrementId($id)
            ->setState('pending_payment', true)
            ->save();

          $out .= $id."\n";
        } catch (Exception $e)  {
          $out .= "Caught exception : ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
        }
      }
    }
    file_put_contents(self::OUT_FILE, $out, FILE_APPEND);
    return true;
  }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

just try to put `$order->setState('pending_payment');
   $order->setStatus('pending_payment'); 
  $order->save();`
I think you are not changing order status that might create problem.

Comment: `setState()` is supposed to set the status as well. So no this doesn't work. Anyway I have solved the problem. See my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to master the Zend queries, so I'm always writing proper MySQL queries when interacting directly with the database. Keep in mind, order status is non-flexible until newer versions of Magento (unless you buy extension).

```
mysql> select status from sales_flat_order group by status;
+-----------------+
| status          |
+-----------------+
| canceled        | 
| closed          | 
| complete        | 
| pending         | 
| pending_payment | 
| processing      | 
+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select state from sales_flat_order group by state;

+-----------------+
| state           |
+-----------------+
| canceled        | 
| closed          | 
| complete        | 
| new             | 
| pending_payment | 
| processing      | 
+-----------------+
6 rows in set (1.03 sec)
```

To help myself understand table structure, I wrote a [php script to make a CSV of all the tables with fields](https://github.com/cacycleworks/mySql_tables_to_csv). So you could get the first bit with `SELECT entity_id, state, status, created_at, increment_id FROM sales_flat_order WHERE status="pending"`. I looked and didn't see "cod_fee" in any of the fieldnames present in my 1.4.2 installation. Note the format of the output of the above query:

```
SELECT entity_id, state, status, created_at, increment_id FROM sales_flat_order WHERE status="pending";
+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
| entity_id | state      | status  | created_at          | increment_id |
+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|      2493 | new        | pending | 2011-09-14 18:09:47 | 200025332    | 
|      2683 | complete   | pending | 2011-10-04 17:19:07 | 200025523    | 
|      2686 | new        | pending | 2011-10-04 20:43:52 | 200025526    | 
|      3022 | processing | pending | 2011-11-15 01:11:34 | 200025849    | 
|      3428 | complete   | pending | 2012-01-12 17:56:57 | 200026236    | 
|      4493 | processing | pending | 2012-04-11 16:16:55 | 200027230    | 
|      5071 | new        | pending | 2012-05-21 18:05:43 | 200027759    | 
|      5091 | new        | pending | 2012-05-22 17:48:11 | 200027779    | 
   ...
|      5399 | new        | pending | 2012-06-14 17:46:46 | 200028069    | 
|      5443 | new        | pending | 2012-06-18 18:50:55 | 200028111    | 
|      5486 | new        | pending | 2012-06-20 21:18:24 | 200028152    | 
|      5491 | new        | pending | 2012-06-20 23:54:53 | 200028157    | 
+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
23 rows in set (0.79 sec)
```